# jquery - how to prevent delayed execution of executeSql?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I am new to jquery mobile.

My issue is first, I have to get a value from database (for QnNumber using the fn toGetQuestionNumber) then use that value in xmlParser function.

If executed in the proper order - the alert should be displayed in the order - First, Second, Third.

But what is shown is the alert is coming as Second, Third, First. (Means the db function toGetQuestionNumber is executed only at the end!)

How to make toGetQuestionNumber execute first - so taht I get the value of QnNumber - then execute xmlParser?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
$('#alpha').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    var day         = getUrlVars()["day"];
    var module      = getUrlVars()["module"];

    var QnNumber=1;


        var db = openDatabase("Exam", "1.0", "The Exam", 200`enter code here`000);
        var dataset;
        var selectAllStatement = "SELECT  TotQn, TotAnswd FROM QuizScore where DayID=" + day + " and ModuleID=" + module ;

        function toGetQuestionNumber() {

            db.transaction(function(tx) 
            {
              tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) 
              {
                dataset = result.rows;
                for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) 
                {
                  item = dataset.item(i);
                  //if(item['TotAnswd']>0)
                  //{
                     QnNumber = item['TotAnswd'];
                     alert('First=' +QnNumber); ////// First Alert
                  //}
                }
              });
            });
      }


    toGetQuestionNumber();
      alert('Second' + QnNumber);  ////// Second Alert


    var xml;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/quiz.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser
        });
    });


         //loading XML file and parsing to .main div.
       function xmlParser(data) 
        {
            xml = data;
            $('#list').empty();

             alert('Third' + QnNumber); ////// Third Alert
        }

    $('#list').trigger('create');


    });
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript never stop

toGetQuestionNumber(); will return directly, it not wait your tx.executeSql

so, alert('Second' + QnNumber); is called first

second, on page ready callback you do the ajax request, but it's not the place to put this ready callback

instead of doing

```
.live
  .ready
```

do

```
.ready
  .live
```

just take in mind that javascript is asynchron, there are some callback after action, like $.ajax and tx.executeSql

if you want a second action called after a first one, launch second action on end callback of the first one

try a thing like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#alpha').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    var day         = getUrlVars()["day"];
    var module      = getUrlVars()["module"];

    var QnNumber=1;

    var db = openDatabase("Exam", "1.0", "The Exam", 200`enter code here`000);
    var dataset;
    var selectAllStatement = "SELECT  TotQn, TotAnswd FROM QuizScore where DayID=" + day + " and ModuleID=" + module ;
    var xml;

    //loading XML file and parsing to .main div.
    function xmlParser(data) 
    {   // if here ajax request is end
        xml = data;
        $('#list').empty();
        alert('Third' + QnNumber); ////// Third Alert

        $('#list').trigger('create');
    }

    function toGetQuestionNumber() {
        db.transaction(function(tx) 
        {
            tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) 
            {
                dataset = result.rows;
                for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) 
                {
                  item = dataset.item(i);
                  //if(item['TotAnswd']>0)
                  //{
                      QnNumber = item['TotAnswd'];
                      alert('First=' +QnNumber); ////// First Alert

                      // if here, db request is end !

                      alert('Second' + QnNumber);  ////// Second Alert

                      // call ajax request

                      $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      url: "data/quiz.xml",
                      dataType: "xml",
                      success: xmlParser
                      });
                  //}
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // start all
    toGetQuestionNumber();

});
});
```

Comment: Hey... It worked like a charm. You rock.. Thanks a lot. Actually I was stuck with this issue & was struggling to get out of it. Now I can proceed with the work. Once again - this is really a great help. I don't know how to express my gratitude...

Comment: Hi, I am trying all the options to play a video file. Pls see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957943/phonegap-video-code-sample. Pls help - if you have come across the same